# Proving nonsingularity of this block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

I have received this question to solve, but, quite frankly, I have no idea how to do it. Can anyone help?

Let $A,B,C,D \in R^{n \times n}$ Show that if $B,D,A-BD^{-1}C$, and $C-DB^{-1}A$ are nonsingular, then
$$\begin{bmatrix}
       A & B\\[0.3em]
       C & D\\[0.3em]
       \end{bmatrix}^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
       (A-BD^{-1}C)^{-1} & (C-DB^{-1}A)^{-1}\\[0.3em]
       -D^{-1}C(A-BD^{-1}C)^{-1} & D^{-1}-D^{-1}C(C-DB^{-1}A)^{-1}\\[0.3em]
       \end{bmatrix}$$

I don't know whether you can apply the same rules as with numerical matrices or not, that's where the root of my problem is. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your alleged inverse is not quite right.  Several typos.

Comment: I adjusted it, typos have been fixed!

Answer (score 1):

Multiplication of block matrices works the same as that of ordinary matrices, except that you have to be careful of the order of things because matrices don't
commute.  Thus
$$ \left[ \matrix{A & B\cr C & D\cr} \right] \left[ \matrix{E & F\cr G & H\cr} \right] = \left[ \matrix{AE+BG & AF + BH\cr CE +DG & CF + DH\cr} \right]$$

So multiply $\left[ \matrix{A & B\cr C & D\cr} \right]$ by its alleged inverse (after you get that corrected), and check that you can simplify the result to $\left[\matrix{I & 0\cr 0 & I}\right]$.